# Unit Testing With SimpleTest in PHP keeping getting file directory errors from relative paths?

Tags: php, zend-framework, simpletest

I am using Zend Framework MVC and unit-testing with SimpleTest library.  I have a specific model that keeps failing because it uses Zend Cache and  the cache directory is a relative path I was wondering if anyone has seen a problem like this b4. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting any PHP errors at all?

Comment: No I am getting an exception here is the exact 
Unexpected exception of type [Zend_Cache_Exception] with message [cache_dir must be a directory] in [C:\wamp\www\music\library\Zend\Cache.php line 208]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make an absolute path using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] that way no matter what file structure I am on it works. a Truly relative path. lol.