# What could change the directory in php Windows besides chdir() and chroot()? (Simpletest include file bug in Windows)

Tags: php, wamp, simpletest, easyphp, getcwd

(Sorry if this is titled poorly.  I'm actually trying to accomplish two things - find out how the current directory can get changed in PHP, and fix a bug in Simpletest running on WAMP.)

I'm running SimpleTest (simpletest.org) on my Windows 7 local machine on EasyPHP (a WAMP variation).

When I run tests, the directory changes from the local script dir back to: C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP\apache according to getcwd().

I created a couple short scripts to examine getcwd() output.  They return the current script path as expected: C:\Users\Burton\Desktop\Sites\dbmover.  The scripts:

serverpath/getcwd.php: `<? echo getcwd(); require_once('tests/getcwd.php) ?>`

serverpath/tests/getcwd.php: `<? echo getcwd(); ?>`

Both return the current path: C:\Users\Burton\Desktop\Sites\dbmover

I did a search through Simpletest source to check for use of chdir() and chroot() - the only ways.  Simpletest doesn't use chdir();

**What else could be changing the path??**

This relative path problem is apparently very common for Simpletest used in Windows.
[This poster on stackoverflow has it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1463557/unit-testing-with-simpletest-in-php-keeping-getting-file-directory-errors-from-re),
as does [this poster](http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/841803-cant-addfile-simpletest-test-suite) elsewhere.

[Some](http://szabgab.com/blog/2009/03/1236753971.html) [people](http://osdir.com/ml/php.simpletest.general/2006-03/msg00011.html) treat the problem as normal, but I think it's a bug.

I've been getting around it myself by using dirname(`__FILE__`) but I'd rather fix it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I have never used simpletest, and without knowing the internals it is difficult to say. However: commands called (exec / system / etc.) could influence the working dir. One of note is that the cgi version of php (not the sapi cli) changes it's working dir  to that of a script, and could possibly be used for `php -l` syntax checks & other applications. If that's the problem, be sure to pass it the `-C` parameter.

Comment: Thanks... it gave me the idea of what else to check.  I didn't find anything you mentioned - but at least I'll know for next time.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the path problem is caused by how Simpletest is run.  It has a cool feature called "autorun", which is basically an include file at the top of the first file calling tests.

It uses register_shutdown_function() which runs just before the script exits.  However, the path as this function runs is [all wrong in many versions of WAMP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.register-shutdown-function.php#92657).

I've submitted [a bug fix for this problem](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3034311&group_id=76550&atid=547458).

BTW, functions that can change the directory in PHP are:
system()
exec()
chdir()
chroot()

Comment: Please accept your nice answer. ;) It'd actually help us (random googlers) quickly skim through the page and immediately see whether it's been solved or not yet.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds more like an include_path problem. What does `echo get_include_path();` reveal?

Comment: It shows .;C:\php5\pear when called from within my test script.  (I don't have a php5 directory).  This is what shows for both the problem script and the dummy test scripts.